# how get min group row only in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Example1:

part of table test1:

```
name|mygroup| scale
----------------
ben | 1   | 1
tom | 1   | 2
jim | 2   | 1
tim | 2   | 2
..
```

the output should be:

```
name|mygroup| scale
----------------
ben | 1   | 1
jim | 2   | 1
```

I try:

```
select name,mygroup,min(scale) from test1 group by mygroup;
```

but it not give proper output.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, you're lucky that it _didn't_.  In mySQL, any column not included in an aggregate or as part of the `GROUP BY` clause has a 'random' (really, undefined) value chosen from those available (per grouping, at least).  In every other RDBMS I'm aware of, this statement would throw an error because `name` wasn't aggregated/grouped.  In mySQL it will **sometimes** return correct results... but you're in _no way whatever_ guaranteed that it will _always_ return correct results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT t.name, t.mygroup, t.scale
    FROM test1 t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT mygroup, MIN(scale) AS MinScale
                        FROM test1
                        GROUP BY mygroup) q
            ON t.mygroup = q.mygroup
                AND t.scale = q.MinScale
```